# Eclipse debug memory usage

Tags: eclipse, debugging, cpu

I'm having some issues debugging with Eclipse. As soon as I launch the debug server, my CPU rockets by 40% - 50%.

How to get by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to have a look at [eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)